# Why there are both filter and access predicates on the same index on this execution plan?

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan, oracle19c, sqlperformance

Considering the execution plan for this query :

```
SQL_ID  1m5r644say02b, child number 0
-------------------------------------
select * from hr.employees where department_id = 80 intersect select * 
from hr.employees where first_name like 'A%'
 
Plan hash value: 1738366820
 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name        | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |             |      1 |        |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       8 |       |       |          |
|   1 |  INTERSECTION                         |             |      1 |        |      4 |00:00:00.01 |       8 |       |       |          |
|   2 |   SORT UNIQUE                         |             |      1 |     34 |     34 |00:00:00.01 |       6 |  6144 |  6144 | 6144  (0)|
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | EMPLOYEES   |      1 |     34 |     34 |00:00:00.01 |       6 |       |       |          |
|   4 |   SORT UNIQUE                         |             |      1 |     11 |     10 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |  2048 |  2048 | 2048  (0)|
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| EMPLOYEES   |      1 |     11 |     10 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |       |       |          |
|*  6 |     INDEX SKIP SCAN                   | EMP_NAME_IX |      1 |     11 |     10 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |       |       |          |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   3 - filter("DEPARTMENT_ID"=80)
   6 - access("FIRST_NAME" LIKE 'A%')
       filter("FIRST_NAME" LIKE 'A%')
```

The execution plan has both access and filter predicates with the same `A%` predicate here on the `EMP_NAME_IX` index. But shouldn't the access predicate be enough here, as they both will filter the same rows? Why did it perform the additional filter predicate?

Is there a general rule for when both access and filter are the same? Based on `GV$SQL_PLAN`, when an operation has either an access or a filter predicate, they are only equal about 1% of the time. And this situation only happens with  operations and options like INDEX (FULL/RANGE/SKIP/UNIQUE) and SORT (JOIN/UNIQUE).

```
select *
from gv$sql_plan
where access_predicates = filter_predicates;
```

Comment: Did you look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464469/access-and-filter-predicates-in-oracle-execution-plan

Comment: @MorticiaA.Addams The questions are similar but not quite identical. In the other question, the FILTER and ACCESS are similar but not identical. When the predicates are slightly different, Jeff's answer makes sense - Oracle may have to ACCESS more data than necessary, and then have to re-FILTER to get the exact rows. But why would that behavior be necessary when there's only a single predicate? (Although I wonder if the answer for the two questions is similar - it is somehow related to multi-column indexes where some columns are skipped.)

Comment: [Answer on the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1472130/10100881)

Answer (score -1):

Presumably you have an index on `hr.employees` that includes the `first_name` column. But you are selecting `*` from `hr.employees` such that the rows obtained from the index would have to traced back (i.e. join) with the table.

For conceptual understanding it helps to think of indexes as plain tables with a foreign key to the original table's primary key. When usage of indexes helps, these two tables are joined. The index is used alone when it contains all needed columns.

In this case we assume a join is required since you are selecting `*`. When `access`ing the `hr.employee` table for the second query of the `intersect`, because its `where` clause `filter`s on an index column, a join to the index is performed prior to filtering.

The first occurrence of `"FIRST_NAME" LIKE 'A%'` is the reason usage of the index is decided. The second occurrence, is then the actual filtering. Filtering happens only once, not twice.

These are listed as distinct operations as deciding to use the index (and therefore perform the join) has its own costs.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct because it's rare for Oracle to use both an ACCESS and a FILTER for the same condition in the same operation. 99% of the time, only an ACCESS or a FILTER is good enough. There must be something unusual about this query and explain plan.